# How to add CSS styles to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

Quick disclaimer - I'm a javascript rookie. I'm looking at how to add CSS styling to a javascript variable.
Here's a link to my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ehney/169/

What I'd like to do is be able to format the dynamic numbers in the counter. Here's the code I used to attempt to do that

```
var days = document.getElementById("days");
    days.style.color = "blue";
```

This isn't doing anything though. Please help me. I'd like to know how to add other formatting such as like font sizing too.

Please understand that I am able to add the styles to all of the javascript using the 'countdown' getElementById. But I would like to specifically target the variables. Help!!!

Comment: Judging by your JSFiddle, there isn't actually an element called Days, which is why you can't assign a colour to it

Comment: there is no element with id `days` in your code

Comment: You can see in this fiddle that by wrapping your desired text in a `span` with `id="days"` you can fix your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ehney/169/ I would suggest using a class if you want to do this to the value as well as the Days label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the variables values in a span with id/class

```
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Days ' + 'Hours ' + 'Minutes ' + 'Seconds  </br> &nbsp <span id="days">' + days + '</span>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<span id="hours">' + hours + '</span>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<span id="minutes">' + minutes + '</span> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<span id="seconds">' + seconds + '</span>';
```

then define css rules

```
#days {
    color: blue;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4r78h/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. I was able to add whatever CSS styles I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = "strong { color: red }";
document.body.appendChild(css);
```